# Why does leaflet.js 1.3.1 differ between unpkg.com and leafletjs.com?

Tags: leaflet

I downloaded the latest version of leaflet (1.3.1) from leafletjs.com and noticed that it differs from unpkg.com:  https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js

The second line of leaflet.js is:

unpkg.com:

```
* Leaflet 1.3.1, a JS library for interactive maps. http://leafletjs.com
```

zip file from leafletjs.com:

```
 * Leaflet 1.3.1+Detached: ba6f97fff8647e724e4dfe66d2ed7da11f908989.ba6f97f, a JS library for interactive maps. http://leafletjs.com
```

Why is that?  I modified one of the leafletjs.com examples to use a local copy of leaflet which I just downloaded.  It didn't work because the link integrity failed, so I found out that the files are different.  Shouldn't they be identical?

I cloned the git repository and check-out tag v1.3.1.  The commit checksum is the same as the one that appears in the zip file:  ba6f97fff8647e724e4dfe66d2ed7da11f908989

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is strange, there is probably a bug in the release process that makes the download zip file contain a slightly different version from what is published on npm / unpkg.

Yes you are right, these files are supposed to be identical.

As a workaround, you can simply locally save the version that you get from unpkg.com CDN.

The files in the `v1.3.1` tag are correct, you can also use those.

As for the SRI check, it is interesting when you use files hosted somewhere else outside your control, like a CDN. In case that external host is compromised and files are infected, the SRI check will reject them, keeping your visitors safe.

In case you use locally hosted files, i.e. in the same server as your HTML page, SRI is much less interesting: if an attacker can access your server and infect your files, he/she can simply infest your HTML page and modify any SRI hash, or just anything anyway.

As for why the file in the zip does not pass the SRI but mentions the same commit hash as the tag release, it is simply a matter of environmental setting when building the file. Both versions were built from the same commit. But the file in the zip probably was built without the "release" flag, making its introductory print slightly different (it mentions the commit hash instead of just the tag name), hence its SRI hash is different, even though the code content is the same.

Comment: Reported as [Leaflet issue #6062](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/6062).

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer because of entering the bug report to github, which is what I should have done in the first place.